# Doesn't recognize all the whitespace in the split function?

Tags: java

Regarding this function.
There is a way which i couldn't use my regex expression and i do not know why ...

For example:

Using the `String.split("[ ]+");` //should be split if it involves whitespace (for me)

And using it on this example it works fine.

```
3
7
1 1 1
2 1 3
1 4 1
```

But with that example :

```
12
10000
 9 15 16 18 16  2 20  2 10 12 15 13 
20  6  4 15 20 16 13  6  7 12 12 18 
11 11  7 12  5  7  2 14 17 18  7 19 
 7 14  4 19  8  6  4 11 14 13  1  4 
 3  8  3 12  3  6 15  8 15  2 11  9 
16 13  3  9  8  9  8  9 18 13  4  5 
 6  4 18  1  2 14  8 19 20 11 14  2 
 4  7 12  8  5  2 19  4  1 10 10 14 
 7  8  3 11 15 11  2 11  4 17  6 18 
19  8 18 18 15 12 20 11 10  9  3 16 
 3 12  3  3  1  2  9  9 13 11 18 13 
 9  2 12 18 11 13 18 15 14 20 18 10
```

It gives me always a problem ! And don't split it !
I know that the solution for this is to removes all the whitespace at the beginning of each line and then my code will work again ! 
But why should i do that ???
What's the problem with my regex ??

Comment: How about presenting the code you are using, and giving the actual results that it produces rather than "don't split it" (which seems unlikely to be literally true).

Comment: Could it be the input has tabs instead of spaces?

Comment: My code is 
String[] parts ; 
parts = line.split(" +");

If you don't understand it, then too bad for you ;)
It doesn't produce anything less than an error which is already explained on my topic. But thank you anyway ! :) @JohnBollinger

Comment: I think it might be as a result of regular expressions being matched greedily.. the first instance that matches "[ ]" will split, and you will get empty strings in the returned array (docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String). I suggest using tabs instead of spaces to split your columns, or checking for empty strings in the returned array after splitting it on space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use `String.split("\\s");`

Or -

Since your `String.split("[ ]+")` solution work for the first case then you may use -

```
String.trim().split("[ ]+");
```

To remove the blank/spaces from the beginning

Comment: And you also probably want to use: `\\s+` in case there's more than just one whitespace

Comment: But why is that for ? :(  I don't understand why my version shouldn't react ! I mean i have been several online regex, and my solution should be fine ! Thank you it works ! :) But i need some answers about that trick !

Answer (score 1):

If you split a string that starts with whitespace around a regex that matches runs of whitespace, then the first element of the result will be an empty string.  It seems likely that that is what you are characterizing as "[doesn't] split it."

Your best bet is probably to `trim()` the input before splitting, but if you don't want to do that then you can probably use a zero-width assertion to prevent the regex from matching the beginning of the input, maybe `myString.split("(?<=\\S.*)\\s+")`.  Note, however, that if you do that then the first result will contain any leading whitespace that was present in the input.

Comment: THANK YOU !
I consider that the split effect isn't so secure then ! 
Trim function worked for me !